# JDBC installed, but getting error trying to connect to Oracle

Tags: xpages

The sample program that comes with the Extension Library works just fine, but when I try to connect to Oracle I get the following error:

Error while reading the relational data
Error while loading connection ojdbc14
Error loading JDBC driver class oracle.jdbc.Driver.OracleDriver. If running the server, check that the corresponding package is available in the WEB-INF/lib directory. If running the studio, check that the corresponding package is available in your client library.
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver oracle.jdbc.Driver.OracleDriver
Cannot create JDBC driver oracle.jdbc.Driver.OracleDriver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class oracle.jdbc.Driver.OracleDriver in NSF
Cannot find class oracle.jdbc.Driver.OracleDriver in NSF
oracle.jdbc.Driver.OracleDriver

It looks like it can't find the jar file, but the jar file is in the following folder:

Lotus/Domino/notedev/domino/workspace/applications/eclipse/plugins

I believe this is the correct path.

Could it be a rights issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code may not automatically pick up jar files in that directory.

I don't know anything about xpages, but this site shows a manifest file for a notes/domino application, where they specify a class path for the application.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/notes-plugin-eclipse/#N100AC

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I am clueless on how to use it. I'm pretty new to web development as I was a LotusScript programmer. I don't get the above error anymore, but I get this one now:

Comment: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp/env/jdbc/ojdbc14

Comment: That is a JNDI lookup related exception, and it looks odd because it appears that you're trying to look up an oracle driver? (based on the name).  The crux of this error is that some part of your application is doing a lookup for a resource named jdbc/ojdbc14 but it is not mapped into the component environment (the component can't see it).