# JDBC Ordeal: it shouldn't be that difficult (Partial Solved, New Errors)

Tags: jdbc, xpages, lotus-domino

I have been trying to get the JDBC portion of the Extension library to work with our Oracle databases now for about 2 months.  I've worked through various issues and misunderstandings.

Currently, I can run the sample database that comes with the Extension Library with no apparent issues.  But, it doesn't like something about my Oracle setup.  My jdbc file is `ojdbc14.jdbc` and I am using `ojdbc14` as my connection name.

I put the `ojdbc14.jdbc` file in the `WEB-Inf` folder in the package explorer.  I put the `ojdbc14.jar` file in the `Notes\jvm\lib\ext` folder of my client computer and put the `ojdbc.jar` file in the `Lotus/Domino/notedev/domino/workspace/applications/eclipse/plugins` folder of the server.

Here's my jdbc file:

```
<jdbc>
    <driver>oracle.jdbc.Driver.OracleDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin://irmsrv81:1600:pt40/CMIS</url>
    <user>UserName</user>
    <password>Password</password>
</jdbc>
```

When I preview my simple view xpage I get:

Error while reading the relational data
comp/env/jdbc/ojdbc14

and then in the Stack trace I get these errors:

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Error while reading the relational data

java.sql.SQLException

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp/env/jdbc/ojdbc14
```

Here is my sqlQuery property of my viewPanel1:

`select * from CMIS.VCOLLECTION`

I am the person in our organization that is trying to champion XPages as the future of our web development and have a huge demostration presentation in April.  JDBC is a significant piece of that presentation and a pivotal issue with the future of XPages at our company.  If anyone can help, I would be eternally greatful.

`UPDATE - New Errors:`

I had my admin add the path above to the default path of the server and now I believe it is seeing my jar file.  However, I'm getting a new set of errors:

```
Exception
Error while reading the relational data
Error while loading connection ojdbc14
Error parsing XML stream
InputStream cannot be null
```

Then from the Stack Trace:

```
com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Error while reading the relational data
java.sql.SQLException
com.ibm.designer.runtime.resources.ResourceFactoriesException: Error while loading connection ojdbc14
com.ibm.commons.xml.XMLException: Error parsing XML stream
```

Any idea what these mean?

Comment: Need a bit more information - 1. How have you provided the driver for oracle to the runtime? 2. Where have you placed the connection file? 3. Can you post the connection file so we can verify its configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question here and your other related question ( [JDBC installed, but getting error trying to connect to Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675254/jdbc-installed-but-getting-error-trying-to-connect-to-oracle) ) it sounds like you need to add the ojdbc14.jar file to the jvm\lib\ext folder on the server (or somewhere else where the server can see it).

Comment: I have the ojdbc14.jar file in the `Lotus/Domino/notedev/domino/workspace/applications/eclipse/plugins` folder on the server.  I thought it was supposed to find it there.

Comment: I don't know but apparently the server is not seeing the jar file. The jvm\lib\ext folder is based on blog posts on the subject. Give it a try :-)

Comment: I'll try it.  I have to get our admins to do it.  Do I need to have the server rebooted afterwards?

Comment: Well, I think I have the server seeing it now. I had our admin make sure that the default path included the folder where my jar file was located.  So, now I have some new errors.  I'll add them to my original post.