# Where do you find the JDBCProvider Interface?

Tags: eclipse, xpages, lotus-domino

As part of my ongoing JDBC/Oracle saga, I solicited the help of one of our Java/JDBC experts and after receiving some more input via my last question "[For JDBC in XPages, how does the server know the connection information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979248/for-jdbc-in-xpages-how-does-the-server-know-the-connection-information)" we imbarked on creating a plugin for my ojdbc14.jar file.  We got the plugin created and tried to complile it.  It complained that it could not find the JDBCProvider Interface.  My question is where do I find this?  Is this part of the Extension Library files on the Server or is this something completely different?

As always, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

MJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to pick `com.ibm.commons.Extension` in the Extension Point dialog, and then set the type as `com.ibm.commons.jdbcprovider`. Set the class to your JDBC driver provider class (named `com.ZetaOne.JDBC.drivers.DB2.DB2DriverProvider` for example) which i've provided sample code for below  that looks like this (customized to your particular driver, etc)

```
package com.ZetaOne.JDBC.drivers.DB2;

import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.ibm.commons.jdbc.drivers.IJDBCDriverAlias;
import com.ibm.commons.jdbc.drivers.JDBCProvider;

public class DB2DriverProvider implements JDBCProvider {
    public DB2DriverProvider() {
    {

    public Driver loadDriver(String className) throws SQLException {
      if(classNmae.equals(com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.class.getName())) {
        return new com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver();
      }
      return null;
    }
}
```

Assuming you've done everything else needed for the plugin, you should be able to export / create your update site and install the driver.

BTW, you'll be able to read how to setup & deploy and use the JDBC package in ExtLibX in our upcoming book "XPages Extension Library: A Step by Step Guide to the Next Generation of XPage Controls" - available on amazon pre-order at [http://www.amazon.com/XPages-Extension-Library-Step---Step/dp/0132901811](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132901811)

Hope this helps.