# Xpages JDBC DB2

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I´m testing the access to RDBMS through extension library, but there was no sucess. I installed the plugin and the Xpages extension library extended, but when I tested a xpage with combobox that the values are the relational table by the @JdbcDbColumn, the error below display. I´m testing in local in designer not a server.

Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=2, col=8: Error while executing function '@JdbcDbColumn'
comp/env/jdbc/db2

**Updated info:**

I'm using Lotus Notes client version 8.5.3 with UP1 and Extension Library components of relational databases connectivity version 8.5.3.20130315-0724. The content in JDBC file is:

```
<jdbc> <driver>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver>
<url>jdbc:db2://hostname:50000/databasename</url> <user>userdb2</user>     
<password>password</password> </jdbc>
```

From log.nsf:

```
HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException: com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression 
HTTP JVM: CLFAD0134E: Exception processing XPage request. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in c:/Lotus/Notes8/Data/domino/workspace/logs`
```

From log error-log-0.xml:

```
CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown;
CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /Chapter12.nsf/teste_db2.xsp - HTTP Code: 500;
CLFAD0134E: Exception processing XPage request
```

I put try/catch and the catch I put printStackTrace():

```
HTTP JVM: java.sql.SQLException, Caused by:
HTTP JVM: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp/env/jdbc/db2
HTTP JVM: at com.ibm.pvc.jndi.internal.provider.java.FlatMappingContext.lookup(FlatMappingCon‌​text.java:118)
HTTP JVM: at com.ibm.pvc.jndi.internal.provider.java.FlatMappingContext.lookup(FlatMappingCon‌​text.java:140)
HTTP JVM: at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
```

**Further update:**
I moved the connection file "db2.jdbc" to `WebContent/WEB-INF/JDBC` and the driver was found but the error below was displayed:

```
HTTP JVM: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: [ibm] [db2] [jcc] [10109] [10354] The version of the IBM Universal JDBC driver in use is not is licensed for connectivity to banks QDB2 data. 
HTTP JVM: To connect to this DB2 server, get a licensed version of IBM DB2 Universal Driver for JDBC and SQLJ copy. 
HTTP JVM:. An appropriate license file db2jcc_license _ * jar for this target platform must be installed in the classpath of the application. 
HTTP JVM: Connectivity banks QDB2 data is activated by one of the following license files: [db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar].
```

Great! Its working! I included the license file db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar in the directory. The integration with DB2 works in values of a combobos, but when I try to use in a view panel the error "HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception" occurs. What´s wrong?
I configured view panel following the instructions of [NotesIn9 047 Intro to XPages and Relational Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNVnFks9LFs).

Comment: Can you show what code was being executed when the error occurred?

Comment: The code is properties values of the  combobox: return @JdbcDbColumn("db2","CONTA_AUTOMACAO","NOM_TTL_CTA")

Comment: What version of the ExtLib and server are you using? Can you show us the contents of the .jdbc file in your xpages app?

Comment: I,m using Lotus Notes client version 8.5.3 with UP 1 and extension library components of relational databases connectivity version 8.5.3.20130315-0724. The content in JDBC file is:

Comment: <jdbc>
<driver>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver>
<url>jdbc:db2://hostname:50000/databasename</url>
<user>userdb2</user>
<password>password</password>
</jdbc>

Comment: One thing to check: If using it in Designer, double check that you use the update site from the "updateSiteOpenNTF-designer.zip" in the ExtLib release. I've seen issues before when only the "updateSiteOpenNTF.zip" was installed to Designer.
If the correct update site was used, can you give us any more info about the error from the log files?

Comment: I used update site form updateSiteOpenNTF-designer.zip. Follow errors reported in the logs.

Comment: From log.nsf: 15/09/2014 11:40:39   HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException: com.ibm.xsp.exception.EvaluationExceptionEx: Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
15/09/2014 11:40:39   HTTP JVM: CLFAD0134E: Exception processing XPage request. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in c:/Lotus/Notes8/Data/domino/workspace/logs

Comment: From log error-log-o.xml:CLFAD0211E: Exception thrown;CLFAD0246E: Exception occurred servicing request for: /Chapter12.nsf/teste_db2.xsp - HTTP Code: 500;CLFAD0134E: Exception processing XPage request

Comment: That's a very generic error that doesn't really tell us much. In your application, go to the xsp properties and enable "Display XPage runtime error page". Also you could try wrapping your call to @JdbcDbColumn in a try catch statement, and print out the caught exception.

Comment: I put try/catch and the catch I put printStackTrace(). Follow below the return

Comment: 15/09/2014 14:29:11   HTTP JVM: java.sql.SQLException

Comment: 15/09/2014 14:29:11   HTTP JVM: Caused by: 
15/09/2014 14:29:11   HTTP JVM: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp/env/jdbc/db2
15/09/2014 14:29:11   HTTP JVM:  at com.ibm.pvc.jndi.internal.provider.java.FlatMappingContext.lookup(FlatMappingContext.java:118)
15/09/2014 14:29:11   HTTP JVM:  at com.ibm.pvc.jndi.internal.provider.java.FlatMappingContext.lookup(FlatMappingContext.java:140)
15/09/2014 14:29:11   HTTP JVM:  at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:436)
15/09/2014 14:29:11

Comment: That's more helpful. By the way, you should edit the original question to add new info, instead of adding more comments. I have edited the original question for you to add what you've posted so far. Update posted to my answer below as well

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. I´m a new user in this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, my best guess is that it isn't finding the DB2 JDBC driver, as I take it you mean you are previewing the app in the Notes Client? You should copy the DB2 JDBC driver plugin from `C:\<db2-install>\java\db2jcc.jar` to `C:\<client-install>\jvm\lib\ext\`.

Furthermore, you should copy the license file as well, from `C:\<db2-install>\java\db2jcc_license.jar` to `C:\<client-install>\jvm\lib\ext\`.

**Another suggestion:**

It looks like it can't find the jdbc connection file. The file should be namesd `db2.jdbc` in your application, and it should be located in the `WebContent\WEB-INF\jdbc` folder

**Similar previous questions:**

[JDBC installed, but getting error trying to connect to Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675254/jdbc-installed-but-getting-error-trying-to-connect-to-oracle)

[JDBC Ordeal: it shouldn't be that difficult (Partial Solved, New Errors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787525/jdbc-ordeal-it-shouldnt-be-that-difficult-partial-solved-new-errors)

[OpenNTF question](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Extension%20Library/discussions/0299204808B37C7E86257957003AFFEF)

Comment: Hi! I´ve already copy the jar in the diretory that you sad, but it didin´t work.

Comment: Something else to try, add the schema before the table name in the @JdbcDBColumn call

Comment: Yes the name is db2.jdbc and it not is "WebContetnt\WEB-INF\jdbc" folder, it is "WebContetnt\jdbc folder.

Comment: Okay, move the jdbc folder and its content, to the WebContent\WEB-INF folder and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I moved the jdbc and its content to folder WEB-INF and now the connection document was found but the erro was displayed:

Comment: 09/15/2014 16:59:12 HTTP JVM: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: [ibm] [db2] [jcc] [10109] [10354] The version of the IBM Universal JDBC driver in use is not is licensed for connectivity to banks QDB2 data. 
09/15/2014 16:59:12 HTTP JVM: To connect to this DB2 server, get a licensed version of IBM DB2 Universal Driver for JDBC and SQLJ copy.

Comment: 09/15/2014 16:59:12 HTTP JVM:. An appropriate license file db2jcc_license _ * jar for this target platform must be installed in the classpath of the application. 
09/15/2014 16:59:12 HTTP JVM: Connectivity banks QDB2 data is activated by one of the following license files: [db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar].

Comment: You should copy the file "db2jcc_license.jar" from C:\<db2-install>\java\ to C:\<client-install>\jvm\lib\ext\

Comment: I copied the file "db2jcc_license.jar" from C:\<db2-install>\java\ to C:\<client-install>\jvm\lib\ext\ but the error remains.

Comment: The filename should actually be "db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar" from the look of the error. Is that the file that you copied over? See here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21244005.

At this point, it's not an XPages problem any more, the issue is with the JDBC driver configuration

Comment: Ok. I will talking to dba to get the license file. Thanks a lot by support!

Comment: If this answer has helped you, consider accepting the answer. See here for details: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/1463958