# view panel and JDBC DB2 integration in xpages

Tags: jdbc, view, xpages

The integration with DB2 works in values of a combobox, but when I try to use in a view panel the error "HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception" occurs. What´s wrong? I configured view panel following the instructions of [NotesIn9 047 Intro to XPages and Relational Data](http://www.notesin9.com/2012/02/27/notesin9-047-intro-to-xpages-and-relational-data/).

The version is 8.5.3 with UP1 and extended components of extension library of Open NTF. I´m executing xpages in local designer client.
I created a xpages with the view panel and setting the properties:

connectionName: the name of connection name of jdbc file created in WebContent/WEB-INF/jdbc

SqlTable: the name of DB2 table

The view panel has only one column that reference at a column field of DB2 table

Comment: Even though this is a NotesIn9, I can't help you as I didn't do that show.  But I don't think anyone can help you unless you post some relevant code.

Comment: As David says, please provide the code you have used. Also more info such as what domino version (9.0.1?8.5.3?) and what version of the ExtLib you have installed

Comment: The details asked  are in  the top. Thanks

Comment: There was another question in this area recently - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811078/xpages-jdbc-db2/25849863#25849863 - read through that question and the comments for some ideas. First guess is that it can't find the JDBC driver for DB2. You're opening the app locally in the Notes Client, correct?

Comment: Brian, that question that you talked was created for me. This is the question: Why the combobox works with @JdbcDbColumn and the view painel no?

Comment: My mistake, didn't check the user name. As was said though, it'll be easier to help if you provide a code sample. For example, the comment above is the first time you've mentioned @JdbcDbColumn, we didnt know that was what you were using until now

Comment: I created a xpages with the view panel and setting the properties:

connectionName: the name of connection name of jdbc file created in WebContent/WEB-INF/jdbc

SqlTable: the name of DB2 table

The view panel has only one column that reference at a column field of DB2 table

Comment: Markus, 2 hints: a) provide code b) while the @JDBC formulas are *very* tempting, they mangle your UI with the data structure. A clean structure would keep both on arms length (think MVC)

Comment: Stwissel the code is only a xpage with a view panel where the properties listed below were configured

connectionName: the name of connection of jdbc file created in WebContent/WEB-INF/jdbc 
SqlTable: the name of DB2 table The view panel 
Only one column that reference at a column field of DB2 table